# How to update value of a mutable Map which is a value to the key of main Map?

Tags: scala

I have a mutable Map in Scala which is defined as below:

```
scala> var sm = mutable.Map[String, mutable.Map[Int, Int]]()
sm: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int]] = Map()
```

I have a Map which has another Map as its value & inserted values into it as shown below.

```
scala> sm += ("abc" -> mutable.Map(1->0,0->0))
res77: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int]] = Map(abc -> Map(1 -> 0, 0 -> 0))

scala> sm
res78: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int]] = Map(abc -> Map(1 -> 0, 0 -> 0))
```

I have "abc" coming from another file with a value 0 or 1 which I need to validate and get the count of 0s & 1s and update it in the Map `sm`.
Before validating it, I tried to update the values on scala REPL as show below

```
scala> sm += ("abc" -> (1 -> sm("abc")(1)+1))
<console>:27: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
       sm += ("abc" -> (1 -> sm("abc")(1)+1))
```

So I tried to first access the key of `"abc"->1` using `sm("abc")(1)` which gave me the right value `0` and added a value to it which worked fine as well.

```
scala> sm("abc")(1)+2
res90: Int = 2
```

But when I substitute the same expression `sm("abc")(1)` on the Map `sm` to update the value of `sm("abc")(1)`, I see the error message:

```
scala> sm += ("abc" -> (1 -> sm("abc")(1)+2))
<console>:27: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(2)
 required: String
       sm += ("abc" -> (1 -> sm("abc")(1)+2))
scala> var e = sm("abc")(1)+2
e: Int = 2

scala> sm += ("abc" -> (1 -> e ))
<console>:29: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int)
 required: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int]
       sm += ("abc" -> (1 -> e ))
```

This works `sm += ("abc" -> mutable.Map(1 -> e ))` but it replaces the key 0 and results in

```
scala> sm += ("abc" -> mutable.Map(1 -> e ))
res93: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int]] = Map(abc -> Map(1 -> 2))
```

I am not able to understand this error message. Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here and how can I update the Map's -> Map's value and get the output as

```
Map(abc -> Map(1 -> 2, 0 -> 0))
```

Comment: A mutable reference to a mutable object which contains other mutable objects... sounds like you will be having a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. `->` has a higher precedence than `+` so your code is essentially:

   ```
   (1 -> sm("abc")(1)) + 2
   ```

   To make this work, put parenthesis around plus:

   ```
   1 -> (sm("abc")(1) + 2)
   ```

   Then it will give you the same error about `(Int, Int)`.
2. There is no implicit conversion from tuple (`->` creates a tuple) to map, so you need to use explicit constructor.

In the end the working code of your version is:

```
sm += ("abc" -> mutable.Map(1 -> (sm("abc")(1) + 2) ) )
```

However this is not a good practice. You already defined the value as the mutable map, so you don't need to construct a new map every time you update the value. Plus your version also lose the pair `0 -> 0`. You can just do:

```
sm("abc")(1) = sm("abc")(1) + 2
```

`sm` will then be `Map(abc -> Map(1 -> 2, 0 -> 0))`

Another way to solve this using immutable Map. There are many tutorials of this online so I will not repeat here.